# Data-toggle sidebar menu is refreshing page in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I'm using themeforest with bootstrap.

When I click in the menu (data-toggle="sidebar"), it refreshes the page preventing me from viewing the menu.

```
<!-- START MOBILE CONTROLS -->
<div class="container-fluid relative">
     <!-- LEFT SIDE -->
      <div class="pull-left full-height visible-sm visible-xs">
           <!-- START ACTION BAR -->
           <div class="header-inner">
              <a href="#" class="btn-link toggle-sidebar visible-sm-inline-block visible-xs-inline-block padding-5" data-toggle="sidebar">
                <span class="icon-set menu-hambuger"></span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <!-- END ACTION BAR -->
       </div>
       <div class="pull-center hidden-md hidden-lg">
           <div class="header-inner">
               <div class="brand inline">
                   <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo" data-src="assets/img/logo.png" data-src-retina="assets/img/logo.png" width="78" height="22">
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
</div>
<!-- END MOBILE CONTROLS -->
```

In the console, I'm getting the following message:

> [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener
>   due to target being treated as passive : jquery-3.2.1.min.js:6

And inside jquery, the error is in this part:

```
preventDefault: function () ... var a = this.originalEvent; ... a.preventDefault(); ...
```

The error is at: a.preventDefault();

Here's the interesting thing: after several clicks on the menu icon, it shows the menu. That's weird.

Any ideas how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Please post more code, including the html.  Can really help with what you've posted here.

Comment: @sn3ll done man

Comment: Try removing the hash tag from `href="#"`

Comment: @sn3ll already tried it! same effect.